# What is the plural of "scenario"?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, latin

What is the plural of "scenario"? I have always used "scenarios", but have recently come across "scenaria" and "scenarii".  Should I be treating it as an Italian or Latin word?

Comment: It's not Latin. And the only way you could get to _scenaria_ would be by projecting the Italian word back to a (non-existent, as far as I know) Latin word _scenarium_, of which _scenaria_ would indeed be the plural.

Comment: Maybe hypercorrection, as some answers guess.  Or maybe as a joke.

Comment: Since this is not an English word, usual English rules don't apply.
I've been taught to write it scenarii, with insistence from my French teacher. My family agree. Books agree. Doesn't look like it's debatable.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Here are the stats from the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) and the [British National Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/):

| word | COCA | BNC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| scenarios | 3683 | 216 |
| scenaria | 0 | 0 |
| scenarii | 0 | 0 |

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scenario), [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scenario), the American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language, and the Collins English Dictionary only mention *scenarios*.

Comment: Ngram shows pretty much the same.  There are a few brief instants in the 1800s where one of the other pops up ("scenario" didn't really begin becoming popular until about 1900), but this is most likely due to OCR errors.

Answer (score 19):

I am sure they were hypercorrecting: http://www.google.com/search?q=scenario+plur

However they might have been old Italians:

http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sc%C3%A9nario

> Le mot provient de l’italien scenario, « décor de théâtre ». En français, le mot s’est d’abord utilisé sans accent comme en italien, mais cet usage est archaïque.
>
> Ni le pluriel italien archaïque scenarii (ancienne orthographe[1]), ni sa variante francisée scénarii (avec accent aigu) ne sont d'usage courant : le pluriel scénarios est le plus commun en français[2]. Selon l’Académie française, en effet, le mot scénario étant français (en italien, il n'aurait pas d'accent aigu), le pluriel « scénarios » s'impose - exactement comme pour lavabos ou pianos.[3]

> The word comes from Italian *scenario*, “theatre scenery”. In French, the word was originally used without an accent as in Italian, but this is archaic.
>
> Neither the archaic Italian plural *scenarii* (old spelling[1]), nor its French variant *scénarii* (with acute accent) is currently used: the plural *scénarios* is most common in French.  Indeed, according to the Académie Française, since *scénario* is a French word (in Italian, there would be no acute accent), the plural *scénarios* is required — just as in *lavabos*, *pianos*.[3]

A Scenario in Italian is [Sceneggiatura](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sceneggiatura) according to Wikipedia. Not what we are looking for here according to Francesco

Comment: "Sceneggiatura" actually means "script", like in a "script of a movie". A scenario in italian is "Scenografia" when it means "thatre scenery" and is a "scenario" like in "generating scenarios according to some probability distribution".

Comment: Yeah my Italian colleague was not too clear when I asked

Answer (score 17):

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scenarii) reports that the plural of *scenario* is *scenarios*. It also reports that the "hypercorrect" plural of *scenario* is held to be *scenarii* (which is nonstandard and rare) since its etymology is Italian.

> From scenario, the terminal o having been replaced with an i to form its plural, as per the Italian -o → -i pattern for forming plurals, by analogy with concerti and virtuosi. However, the plural of the Italian word scenario is scenari, making “scenarii” etymologically inconsistent.

According to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scenarios) and the [OED](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scenarios), the accepted plural of *scenario* is *scenarios*. The [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=8352434) reports 3683 instances of *scenarios* being used and none of *scenarii*.

Comment: +1 for reading Wiktionary more carefully than I have. (^_^)

Comment: Interesting, but if the quotation in @mplungjan’s entry is accurate, then *scenarii* wouldn’t actually be etymologically inconsistent: *scenari* is the modern spelling of the Italian plural, but *scenarii* was the older form of it, appropriate from when the word was originally borrowed.

Answer (score 3):

“scenarios” is the correct one.

And by the way, in Italian the plural is “scenari” (single i).

Comment: According to the [Wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scenarii), scenarii is old/obsolete but it is not mentioned as incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Scenario is not from Greek as mentioned above, it's from Italian, and Italian is from Latin.

In Latin, Scenario is from "Scaena", which is then changed one last time to become "Scaenarius", to express something in particular and not the "scene" in general.

The Latin declension of Scaenarius in plural Nominal masculine (yes "scenario" is a masculine word) is **Scaenarii**.

https://www.online-latin-dictionary.com/latin-dictionary-flexion.php?lemma=SCAENARIUS100

Scenarios became a recurrent mistake because of the common "s" added at the end of a plural word.

Some books use **Scenarii** as the plural of scenario, and it is a pretty common word in literature.

Comment: Hello, Teva. ELU looks at present English usage; there are many examples where errors made in the past have since been incorporated into grammar or the lexicon and are now acceptable, possibly at the expense of what might be considered more felicitous. Dictionaries pronounce upon what should be now considered acceptable; look at Tragicomic's answer.